# Potential function of a conservative vector field differ by a constant

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be an open, connected set and $F:\, U\longrightarrow\mathbb R^n$ is a $C^1$ vector field. Suppose $f,\,g\,$ be potential function of $F$ on $U$, that is
$$\nabla f=F=\nabla g\ \ \text{on }U.$$

I want to show that $f$ and $g$ differ by a constant. A natural way that many people would do is using the antiderivative like for the 1 variable case. Nevertheless, I got no fascinated going that way, and I felt there're some cool ways with interesting ideas for this problem.

One nice way I found on this forum is : let $h:\ \mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be a map such that $\nabla h=0$ on $\mathbb R^n$. Suppose $h$ is not a constant function, then there exists $a,\,b\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $h(a)\ne h(b)$. Then consider a function $z$ defined by
\begin{align}
z:\ [0,1]&\longrightarrow\mathbb R
\\ t&\longmapsto z(t)=h\big((1-t)a+tb\big)
\end{align}
Since $z$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $(0,1)$ and $z(0)=h(a)\ne z(1)=h(b)$ thus by Mean value theorem,
$$\exists\,c\in(0,1):\ z'(c)=z(1)-z(0)=h(a)-h(b)\ne0.$$
Otherwise, by the chain rule
$$z'(c)=\nabla h\big((1-c)a+cb\big)\cdot(b-a)=0\ \ \text{since }\nabla h=0\ \text{on }\mathbb R^n, $$
which is a contradiction. Then $h$ is const on $\mathbb R^n$. Let $h=f-g$ and we completed the proof.

That is a quite nice idea for this problem. So I have tried applying it into my problem here. I let $h:\ U\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ as done above. But then I figured out that the domain in the problem is not $\mathbb R^n$, but an open set $U$. The issue is $U$ is not supposed to be convex, so in this case $(1-c)a+cb$ needs not to be in $U$, and thus we don't have $\nabla h\big((1-c)a+cb\big)=0$.

Now, I have an idea for that :

- Give a point $x\in U$. Since $U$ is an open set, it contains an open ball $B_r(x)$. I simply admit the convexity of $B_r(x)$ and and use it for my proof.
- Next, if $h$ is constant on $B_r(x)$, I could somehow show that $h$ must be constant on $U$ (this is a known fact : locally constant on a connected set implies global constant).
- Now, suppose $h$ is not constant on $B_r(x)$. Here I can apply the method of preceeding proof since $B_r(x)$ is convex. Hence, $h$ must be constant on $B_r(x)$ and therefore it is constant on $U$.

What do you think about my idea ? May you hint me some other nice way to solve this problem ? I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic strategy works here even if $U$ is not convex. As you say, suppose that $h:U\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $\nabla h=0$, but that there are $a,b\in U$ so that $h(a)\neq h(b)$. Since $U$ is open and connected in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is also path connected and so you can find a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to U$ connecting $a$ and $b$. As you mentioned, each point along this path is the center of a little convex ball contained in $U$, which gives a covering of this path by open sets. By compactness, only finitely many of these are necessary to cover the path and so our path is covered by finitely many convex sets.

Using these finitely many convex sets you can find a *piecewise* straight path in $U$ connecting $a$ and $b$. Let's say we have named the pieces $l_1,\ldots l_k$. Your argument above says that $h$ is constant on each of the $l_i$ and hence constant on the whole path. Thus $h(a)=h(b)$.

Hence any two potential functions must differ by a constant.

Comment: that was a very interesting proof, thank you. In the case that the concept of path-connected was not mentioned in advance, do you know another way to show this problem ?

Comment: @PermQi, Path connectedness is not an extra hypothesis in this case because for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ a set is connected if and only if it is path connected.

Comment: I don't think so, the sine curve is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is connected but not path connected

Comment: @PermQi You are right. What I should have said was open + connected implies path connected in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I assume you mean the "topologist sine curve", but this is not open and so it doesn't contradict what I mentioned.  I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I think in your proof above, when we had the path $\gamma$, we should apply the Newton-Leibniz theorem there for the function $h=f-g$. Then we can show the contradiction right there.