# Functions with equal gradient and path-connected open domain

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, path-connected

Consider the following exercise:

---

**(1.1)** If $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ are functions such that their partial derivatives exist (but are not necessarily differentiable) and $\nabla f(x)=\nabla g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $f$ and $g$ differ by a constant

**(1.2)** Show that the same conclusion holds if $f,g$ don't have $\mathbb{R}^n$ as their domain, but instead, their domain is a pathwise-connected open set.

---

I have proved **(1.1)** (using the fact that if $\nabla f(x)=(0,...,0)$ on all its domain, then $f$ is constant on its domain) but I don't see a way to prove **(1.2)** , more specifically; I don't see a way to use the hypothesis given in the last part of the exercise

Comment: Or perhaps this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778773/potential-function-of-a-conservative-vector-field-differ-by-a-constant/4778864#4778864

Comment: @SamBallas That's exactly what I needed to see. Thanks!